# query search LIKE use keywords where and left join LARAVEL 5

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-5

I want to find a data from two tables based on the name contained in the users, but I am having problems.
This is the users table containing the id, and name.
This is the student table that contains the id, and user_id.
Where user_id student = id users.

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
  $keywords   = trim($request->input('keywords'));

  if (!empty($keywords)) { 
      $id_class       = $request->input('id_class');

    //Query
    $query = User()
    ->leftjoin('student', 'users.id', '=', 'student.user_id')
    ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%');

    (!empty($id_class)) ? $query->Kelas($id_class) : ''; 
    $data_student = $query->paginate(10); 

    //URL link pagination
    $pagination = (!empty($id_class)) ? $pagination = $data_student->appends(['id_class' => $id_class]) : '';
    $pagination = $data_student->appends(['keywords' => $keywords]);

    $amount_data = $=data_student->total();
    return view('student.index', compact('data_student', 'keywords', 'pagination', 'amount_data', 'id_class'));
   }
   return redirect('student');
}
```

Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\User()

Comment: What kind of problems are you having?

Comment: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\User()

Comment: Try adding `use App\User` after the `namespace` definition

Comment: done, but the result is same

Comment: Can you share your uses? Also what's the correct namespace for your `User` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned previously you need to correctly refer to the User class with namespace, you also need to change thew following:

```
 $query = User()
    ->leftjoin('student', 'users.id', '=', 'student.user_id')
    ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%');
```

to:

```
$query = User::leftjoin('student', 'users.id', '=', 'student.user_id')
    ->where('users.name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%');
```

You must call the first method on the class as static with `::`.

Also another potential typo you join the table `student` should it be plural; `students`?

Comment: are you kidding me? `User()::leftjoin` ? this would throw a fatal error.

Comment: He's just missing the User instantiation by the `new` keyword.

Comment: I don't remember if `(new User)->leftJoin()` would work. I'm not working with eloquent anymore (Doctrine better) but if it doesn't work so you're right and it would be `User::leftJoin()->...`.

Comment: I use Laravel and Eloquent daily and this is definitely how its done ;-)

Comment: Ok nice, it is sure that your answer will work for him :)